# Prove that $f: (a,b)→ℂ$ cannot have infinitely many zeros in $(a,b)$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, analyticity

I have the following nonzero analytic function: $f:ℂ→ℂ$. We will consider only the restriction $f: (a,b)→ℂ$, $a,b∈ℝ$ and $a<b$.

My **question** is: Prove that $f: (a,b)→ℂ$ cannot have infinitely many zeros in $(a,b)$.

**Hint**: Use the fact that $f$ is a nonzero entire function and the interval $(a,b)$ have an accumulation point.

Comment: Yes, use the hint. First I thought $f(z)=\sin\left(\frac1{z-a}\right)$ is a counterexample, but your $f$ is supposed to be entire, not just analytic on $(a,b)$.

Comment: if $a_n$ is a sequence of different zeros, it has a convergent subseqence. so $f$ is constant on a convergent sequence. so it's constant.

Comment: @CutieKrait: ...and what is the relation of this sequence with the interval $(a,b)$?

Comment: this sequence is in [a,b].

Comment: @CutieKrait: But in the exercice $f$ is defined in the open interval.

Comment: so what do you mean by "entire"?

Comment: @CutieKrait: has a taylor series in the whole complex plane.

Comment: so it's defined everywhere including [a,b], any sequence in (a,b) is also in [a,b] an so it has a convergent subsequnce. this convergent subsequence is in (a,b)

Comment: @CutieKrait: Ok and thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by **CutieKrait**, if $(a_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence of different zeros of $f$, then it must has a convergent subseqence. so $f$ is constant on a convergent sequence. so it's constant since the interval $(a,b)$ have an accumulation point.